# Ignore missing indexes in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a two node cluster setup in ElasticSearch. I have certain data that is set to only be stored on the master node (configured by setting `index.routing.allocation.include._name=MACHINE_NAME`).

However when the master node goes down, I would like the worker node to become the new master and continue functioning as normal. Unfortunately, it is aware of the indexes that were only stored on the previous master node and so it remains in a red cluster health state until the other node comes back online. Is there a way for it to ignore these indexes?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by normal? If you do not want your queries to say that a targetted index is missing you can query index_name* instead of index_name (make sure it will not match more than one index tough)

Comment: Hi @Pandawan, I do realize that you can do that. The problem isn't querying data from ElasticSearch, but that the cluster state is red at that time because it expects to see those indexes which are only stored on the previous master node. The project I'm working on relies on the cluster health to determine when ElasticSearch is fully initialized. When I say "as normal", I want the cluster health to be yellow.